# In Entity Framework how to call stored procedure?

Tags: wcf

i added the tables using entity framework to my solution.

please tell me how to call stored procedure in entity framework.

i am directly calling the SP as usual like this but it is not called.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "LoginValidation?emailid={emailid}&password={password}&id={id}", Method = "POST")]
        public string Insert(string emailid, string password, string aid)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataEntities"].ConnectionString);
           // Validation validation = new Validation();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VerifyAndRetreiveUser", con);
                con.Open();

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@emailid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = emailid;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 string result = cmd.Parameters["@result"].ToString();
                 return result;

            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                string msg = "Exception occured while validating user. " + exc.Message;
                if (exc.InnerException != null)
                    msg += exc.InnerException.Message;



                return msg;
            }

        }
```

that stored procedure is not calling in entity framework .pls help me

Comment: That doesn't look like EF to me - it looks like plain old ADO.NET...?

Comment: please tell me can we call that sp in entity framework. or please tell me how to call the stored procedure in entity framework

Comment: Omg did you at least tried to search it on google? Have you heard about MSDN (documentation)?